# Trigger WhatsApp message when someone from google sheets

Tags: javascript, automation, twilio, whatsapp, twilio-api

Is it possible to automatically send WhatsApp messages if someone fills my google form,currently storing data into a google sheet. In this form, users fill in their Name and phone number. I want to automatically send them a welcome message when they fill the form. I have successfully sent a welcome email in a similar google form with the help of App Script.

This is what I did in case of email:

```
function sendMail() {
  
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("CRM").activate()
  
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
  var lr = ss.getLastRow();
  
  var quotaLeft = MailApp.getRemainingDailyQuota();
//  Logger.log(quotaLeft)
  
  if((lr-1) > quotaLeft){
    Browser.msgBox("You have only " + quotaLeft + " E-mail left, mails were not sent")
  } else{
    
      for(var i=2; i<=lr;i++){
      
        var currentEmail = ss.getRange(i, 1).getValue();
        var currentSub = ss.getRange(i, 3).getValue();
        var currentName = ss.getRange(i, 2).getValue();
        var templateText = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Templates").getRange(i, 2).getValue();
        var name = templateText.replace("{name}", currentName);
       
        MailApp.sendEmail(currentEmail, currentSub, name)     
        
      }
    Browser.msgBox("Welcome emails sent")
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's possible if you use twillo. Try the below code

```
function sampletTextMessage(){
  var ACCOUNT_SID = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var ACCOUNT_TOKEN = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";
  var options = {
    "method" : "post",
    'headers' : {
      "Authorization" : "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(ACCOUNT_SID + ":" + ACCOUNT_TOKEN),
    },
    'payload' :{
      'Body' : 'Your Twilio code is 1238432',
      'To' : 'whatsapp:+91XXXXXXXXX3',
      'From': 'whatsapp:+1XXXXXXXXX6',
    },
    'muteHttpExceptions' : true
  };
  var url="https://api.twilio.com/2010-04-01/Accounts/" + ACCOUNT_SID + "/Messages.json";
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url,options);
  Logger.log(response);
}
```

Comment: Use capital first letters in "Body", "To" and "From". Else it gives error.

'payload' :{
      'Body' : 'Your Twilio code is 1238432',
      'To' : 'whatsapp:+91XXXXXXXXX3',
      'From': 'whatsapp:+1XXXXXXXXX6',

Answer (score 0):

Register in https://panel.rapiwha.com/landing/login.php. Link your number and get the API Key.

Put the below code in your sheet
Install a Trigger "On Form Submit"

```
//
//
function onFormSubmit(e) {

  var today=new Date();
  var shtname = e.source.getActiveSheet().getName();
  switch (shtname) {
  case "SaleOrder":
    var resp = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1, e.range.rowStart,4 ).getValues();
    //name is the first question
    //mobile no is second question (with country code, without + sign)
    var api_key="xxxxxx"; //from rapiwah
    var wup = "Dear " +resp[0][1]+" Thank you for contacting us. We will get back yo you soon";
    var formurl2= 'https://panel.rapiwha.com/send_message.php?apikey='+api_key+'&number=' + resp[0][2] +'&text='+wup;
    var formurl3 = formurl2.replace(/#/g, "");
    var formurl4 = formurl3.replace(/,/g, "");
    var formurl = formurl4.replace(/ /g, "%20");
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(formurl);

    break;
    //
    default:
    break;
  }
}
```